# Two way to use of Classes in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance

This question sounds weird , Reason to post it because its always a big confusion in mind 
Below is my code using Inheritance

```
class Program:Identity
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Identity id = new Identity();
            Console.WriteLine(id.name);
            Console.WriteLine(id.age);
            Console.WriteLine(id.DOB);
            Console.WriteLine(id.employed);
            Console.WriteLine(id.grade);
            Console.WriteLine(id.experience);
            Console.WriteLine(id.metric);
            Console.WriteLine(id.intermediate);
            Console.WriteLine(id.UG);
            Console.WriteLine(id.PG);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Identity:Occupation
    {
        public string name{ get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
        public Identity()
        {
            name = "Mr. Xyz";
            age = 35;
            DOB = DateTime.Now.Date;
        }
    }

   class Occupation:Education
    {
        public string employed { get; set; }
        public string grade { get; set; }
        public int experience { get; set; }
        public Occupation()
        {
            employed = "employed-yes";
            grade = "B-Level";
            experience = 2;   
        }
    }

    class Education
    {
        public string metric { get; set; }
        public string intermediate { get; set; }
        public string UG { get; set; }
        public string PG { get; set; }
        public Education()
        {
            metric = "metric-yes";
            intermediate = "intermediate-yes";
            UG = "UG-yes";
            PG = "PG-No";
        }
    }
```

**2.] Now the same code using external class file**

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.set_values();
            Console.WriteLine(p.name);
            Console.WriteLine(p.age);
            Console.WriteLine(p.DOB);
            Console.WriteLine(p.employed);
            Console.WriteLine(p.grade);
            Console.WriteLine(p.experience);
            Console.WriteLine(p.metric);
            Console.WriteLine(p.intermediate);
            Console.WriteLine(p.UG);
            Console.WriteLine(p.PG);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
class Person
    {
        public string name;
        public int age;
        public DateTime DOB;
        public string employed;
        public string grade;
        public int experience;
        public string metric;
        public string intermediate;
        public string UG;
        public string PG;

        public void set_values()
        {
            name = "Mr. ABC";
            age = 20;
            DOB = DateTime.Now.Date;
            employed = "employed-No";
            grade = "None";
            experience = 2;
            metric = "metric-yes";
            intermediate = "intermediate-yes";
            UG = "UG-No";
            PG = "PG-No";
        }

    }
```

My question is what is the benefits of inheritance and when to use it , I was always able to use another classes by creating there object , never use inheritance in my little programming life .
Can somebody enlighten this - when and why inheritance .
Please let me know if this question is not clear to you , I will try to make it more clear.

Comment: I think your example is not a good one, since `Occupation` is not a specialized form of `Education` and an `Identity` is not a special form of `Occupation` (well, some students of philosophy might want to disagree, but thats not the point) and `Identity` is not a `Program`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think about creating an inheritance hierarchy `class B : A`, ask yourself the following questions:

- Is every `B` an `A`?

  - if not, don't use inheritance, design them separately
- Is every `A` a `B`?

  - if so, don't use inheritance, instead design them as one class
- Is there any use for `A` without `B` in my program?

  - if not, don't use inheritance, it would be over-engineering. Instead design them as one class

Now, if you reached this point, you can actually design them as inheritance hierarchy. At this point, also the benefits should become clear. If you instead reached one of the branch solutions in my list, it's perfectly understandable that you don't see the benefits when applying inheritance to the problem.

*This list might still be incomplete, consider it a starting point only*

Comment: Thanks , but if every B an A or they have similar or related property - than inheritance fits well but is not using a separate class file for the same is more modular ?

Comment: @Saurabh Inheritance doesn't really care about files... ofcourse you should write each class into a separate file for a serious project. Also, stop talking about *"or they have similar or related property"* as if it was the same thing as *"B is an A"*. These are completely different cases and just some similarity is not enough to go for inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

There are pretty many reasons why you need to do that.

- It will be required when you deserialize a DB response or JSON data which is in normalized format as the class structure you have mentioned in the first example.
- Modularized code is always easier to handle
- You can reuse the class to define different sets of data which do not fall in same structure (or can say handle inconsistent data)
- Base class can be reused to define another set of derived class

There are still more reason why to go for inheritance. You can always google and see why it is useful

Comment: there is very little info on google which is usefull , its almost nothing . By the way thanks for the response